# Where is Steinbeck's "Salinas Valley"?

Tags: usa, california, locate-this

I live in the South-Eastern US and am planning a long road trip out West.  One of the things I've always wanted to experience for myself is the beautiful Salinas Valley which Steinbeck describes so vividly in his novels.

Unfortunately, "Salinas Valley" doesn't seem to be a recognized landmark or state park.  I've of course found the city of Salinas, CA, but I'm unsure if this is any more than just another city.  Perhaps the "valley" lies elsewhere, somewhere close to that, but you have to know where and how to get there.

Does anyone know where I can go to see for myself the landscape he was writing about?

Comment: Remember that Steinbeck was describing California from the perspective of people who had watched their farms destroyed, and then spent a long journey through arid, sparsely-populated lands. Their idea of "beauty" and a "land of plenty" might be very different from yours. Unless, of course, you like agriculture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salinas_Valley) tells us that is a 90 mile long valley in Northern California, the city of Salinas is at the northwestern end of the valley, the Salinas rivers flows all along the valley. Steinbeck's novels where all over the valley, I don't know about any specific location worth checking out.

Comment: Since a picture is equal to 1,000 words, and assuming that the path was via Route 66 to El Camino Real, here's what the view would be as you leave the mountains: https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Salinas,+CA&aq=0&oq=salinas&sll=35.634977,-117.504272&sspn=3.95063,8.453979&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Salinas,+Monterey+County,+California&ll=35.994952,-120.87347&spn=0.122914,0.264187&t=h&z=13